# Incrementally Trainable Entity Recognition Classifier

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, classification, semantic-web

I'm doing some semantic-web/nlp research, and I have a set of sparse records, containing a mix of numeric and non-numeric data, representing entities labeled with various features extracted from simple English sentences.

e.g.

```
uid|features
87w39423|speaker=432, session=43242, sentence=34, obj_called=bob,favorite_color_is=blue
4535k3l535|speaker=512, session=2384, sentence=7, obj_called=tree,isa=plant,located_on=wilson_street
23432424|speaker=997, session=8945305, sentence=32, obj_called=salty,isa=cat,eats=mice
09834502|speaker=876, session=43242, sentence=56, obj_called=the monkey,ate=the banana
928374923|speaker=876, session=43242, sentence=57, obj_called=it,was=delicious
294234234|speaker=876, session=43243, sentence=58, obj_called=the monkey,ate=the banana
sd09f8098|speaker=876, session=43243, sentence=59, obj_called=it,was=hungry
...
```

A single entity may appear more than once (but with a different UID each time), and may have overlapping features with its other occurrences. A second data set represents which of the above UIDs are definitely the same.

e.g.

```
uid|sameas
87w39423|234k2j,234l24jlsd,dsdf9887s
4535k3l535|09d8fgdg0d9,l2jk34kl,sd9f08sf
23432424|io43po5,2l3jk42,sdf90s8df
09834502|294234234,sd09f8098
...
```

What algorithm(s) would I use to **incrementally** train a classifier that could take a set of features, and instantly recommend the N most similar UIDs and probability of whether or not those UIDs actually represent the **same** entity? Optionally, I'd also like to get a recommendation of missing features to populate and then re-classify to get a more certain matches.

I researched traditional approximate nearest neighbor algorithms. such as [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN) and [ANN](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.ann), and I don't think these would be appropriate since they're not trainable (in a supervised learning sense) nor are they typically designed for sparse non-numeric input.

As a very naive first-attempt, I was thinking about using a naive bayesian classifier, by converting each SameAs relation into a set of training samples. So, for each entity A with B sameas relations, I would iterate over each and train the classifier like:

```
classifier = Classifier()
for entity,sameas_entities in sameas_dataset:
    entity_features = get_features(entity)
    for other_entity in sameas_entities:
        other_entity_features = get_features(other_entity)
        classifier.train(cls=entity, ['left_'+f for f in entity_features] + ['right_'+f for f in other_entity_features])
        classifier.train(cls=other_entity, ['left_'+f for f in other_entity_features] + ['right_'+f for f in entity_features])
```

And then use it like:

```
>>> print classifier.findSameAs(dict(speaker=997, session=8945305, sentence=32, obj_called='salty',isa='cat',eats='mice'), n=7)
[(1.0, '23432424'),(0.999, 'io43po5', (1.0, '2l3jk42'), (1.0, 'sdf90s8df'), (0.76, 'jerwljk'), (0.34, 'rlekwj32424'), (0.08, '09843jlk')]
>>> print classifier.findSameAs(dict(isa='cat',eats='mice'), n=7)
[(0.09, '23432424'), (0.06, 'jerwljk'), (0.03, 'rlekwj32424'), (0.001, '09843jlk')]
>>> print classifier.findMissingFeatures(dict(isa='cat',eats='mice'), n=4)
['obj_called','has_fur','has_claws','lives_at_zoo']
```

How viable is this approach? The initial batch training would be horribly slow, at least O(N^2), but incremental training support would allow updates to happen more quickly.

What are better approaches?

Comment: Interesting question, as always Cerin. When you say you want to train incrementally, does that mean you  acquire more entity data, more 'sameas' data or both?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more of a clustering than a classification problem. Your entities are data points and the sameas data is a mapping of entities to clusters. In this case, clusters are the distinct 'things' your entities refer to.

You might want to take a look at semi-supervised clustering. A brief google search turned up the paper [Active Semi-Supervision for Pairwise Constrained Clustering](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ml/papers/semi-sdm-04.pdf) which gives pseudocode for an algorithm that is incremental/active and uses supervision in the sense that it takes training data indicating which entities are or are not in the same cluster. You could derive this easily from your sameas data, assuming that - for example - uids `87w39423` and `4535k3l535` are definitely distinct things.

However, to get this to work you need to come up with a distance metric based on the features in the data. You have a lot of options here, for example you could use a simple Hamming distance on the features, but the choice of metric function here is a little bit arbitrary. I'm not aware of any good ways of choosing the metric, but perhaps you have already looked into this when you were considering nearest neighbour algorithms.

You can come up with confidence scores using the distance metric from the centres of the clusters. If you want an actual probability of membership then you would want to use a probabilistic clustering model, like a Gaussian mixture model. There's quite a lot of software to do Gaussian mixture modelling, I don't know of any that is semi-supervised or incremental.

There may be other suitable approaches if the question you wanted to answer was something like "given an entity, which other entities are likely to refer to the same thing?", but I don't think that is what you are after.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. However, the reason why I still think this is a classification, and not a clustering problem, is that clustering generally attempts to fit a vector into a *single* cluster without any confidence score. I suppose you could use the distance metric to measure how far away a vector is from each cluster, but I'm not sure how that would translate into a probability.

Comment: @Cerin So, is the problem that you want some kind of confidence score of membership, that you want a actual probability of membership or you want entities to have membership of multiple clusters?

Comment: @Cerin as in, a given entity can genuinely belong to to multiple 'things' (in terms of the ground truth)

Comment: Good question. The more I think about it, the more it seems that supervised clustering == classification. I suppose I'm looking for an entity to belong to multiple groups/things. For example, "my apple" would belong to one "thing" representing a specific apple belonging to me, but it might also belong to another "thing" representing "fruit", and other groups representing hypernyms/holonyms.

Comment: I suppose supervised clustering is quite like a generative classification algorithm (e.g. naive bayes), less so for something discriminative like logistic regression. However the above algorithm is semi-supervised, so it does train its model on unlabelled examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this method:

> "Large Scale Online Learning of Image Similarity Through Ranking" Gal Chechik, Varun Sharma, Uri Shalit and Samy Bengio, Journal of Machine Learning Research (2010). 
>   [[PDF](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/chechik10a/chechik10a.pdf)] [[Project homepage](http://robotics.stanford.edu/~gal/Research/OASIS/)]

More thoughts:

What do you mean by 'entity'? Is entity the thing that is referred by 'obj_called'? Do you use the content of 'obj_called' to match different entities, e.g. 'John' is similar to 'John Doe'? Do you use proximity between sentences to indicate similar entities? What is the greater goal (task) of the mapping?

Comment: In my case, "entity" is no single piece of text. It's more of a "virtual" object, similar to the concept of a group in a clustering algorithm. The greater goal is to better build a model from natural language by linking together attributes defined in separate sentences that refer to the same entity. i.e. I just want to better understand the subject of "entity recognition".